# Send secure data from Android app to PHP page

Tags: php, android, encryption, https, android-volley

I have develop an app that communicates with my web server via the Volley library. Communication occurs by exchanging strings in POST.

My server uses HTTPS, so I think the data being exchanged is safe. But I think it is better to encrypt the data.

I searched, also here on stackoverflow, how to encrypt data on Android and decrypt it on PHP (and viceversa), but I only found old answers. For example in some posts they advised to use mcrypt, but this is deprecated.

I ask you, how can I exchange data between an Android app and PHP safely? Or, is HTTPS enough without any other encryption?

Thanks for your help

Comment: If you don't want encryption, then you can convert date string to byte array and from backend side convert byte array to string

Comment: @Sniffer: How is the security of a byte array comparable to encryption?

Comment: I tried with the byte array, and then modified it to my liking to "encrypt" it. But I can't use very long strings.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware not related to encryption but it's not human-readable/understandable